# Adding certain columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
    A  B  C  D  E

J   4  2  3  2  3
K   5  2  6  2  1
L   2  6  5  4  7
```

I would like to create an additional column that adds by index the `df` except column `A`  (which also are numbers), therefore what I have tried is :

```
df['summation'] = df.iloc[:, 1:4].sum(axis=0)
```

However, the column `summation` is added but gives `NaN` values.

Desired output is:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  summation

J   4  2  3  2  3    10
K   5  2  6  2  1    11
L   2  6  5  4  7    22
```

The sum along the row starting at `B` to the end.

Comment: `df.sum(1)` you need add on row level.

Comment: @Wen thnks for your input! but i would like to sum from `loc.['B']` 1 along the row

Comment: Did you try with `axis=1`?

Comment: Ok, Your column one is str, so it will not count in sum, you can just do df.sum(1)

Comment: The only thing wrong in your approach is the axis. If you pass `axis=0` it will take the sum for each column. Since this cannot be aligned with row labels, it will give NaNs. Just change the axis parameter. A label friendly way is `df.loc[:, 'B':].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @ayhan: Might be nice if you added your solution as an answer so that people quickly find it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you apply `sum` on the wrong axis. If you want to exclude columns from the sum, you can use `drop` (which also accepts a list of column names which might be handy if you want to exclude columns at e.g. index 0 and 3; then `iloc` might not be ideal)

```
df.drop('A', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

which yields

```
J    10
K    11
L    22
```

Also @ayhan's solution in the comments works fine.